# vscode python lint problem at the first column of first line

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylance, pyright

I have python modules that I run in VSCode for development.
And everything works fine until today VSCode suddenly said that one of the module had some binding problem and made the file name tab red.
VSCode the problem occurs in the first character of the first line which is the following standard line at every module of my program.

```
from __future__ import print_function    # (at top of module)
```

But strangely VSCode did not raise the same problem for other module that starts with the same line.
The problem message is like this.

```
An internal error occurred while binding file "aModule.py": Error: Debug Failure. createKeyForReference received unexpected expression type
at createKeyForReference (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\codeFlowTypes.ts:240:9)
at createKeyForReference (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\codeFlowTypes.ts:218:25)
at C.visitAssignment (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\binder.ts:849:50)
at C.visitNode (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\parseTreeWalker.ts:132:29)
at C.walk (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\parseTreeWalker.ts:98:37)
at forEach (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\parseTreeWalker.ts:107:22)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at C.walkMultiple (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\parseTreeWalker.ts:105:15)
at C.walk (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\parseTreeWalker.ts:100:18)
at C._walkStatementsAndReportUnreachable (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\binder.ts:2583:22)
at C.visitSuite (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\binder.ts:345:14)
at C.visitNode (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\parseTreeWalker.ts:330:29)
at C.walk (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\parseTreeWalker.ts:98:37)
at callback (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\binder.ts:1290:22)
at C._trackCodeFlowExpressions (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\binder.ts:3236:9)
at C.visitIf (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\binder.ts:1265:48)
at C.visitNode (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\parseTreeWalker.ts:184:29)
at C.walk (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\parseTreeWalker.ts:98:37)
at C._walkStatementsAndReportUnreachable (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\binder.ts:2583:22)
at C.visitSuite (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\binder.ts:345:14)
at C.visitNode (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\parseTreeWalker.ts:330:29)
at C.walk (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\parseTreeWalker.ts:98:37)
at Object.callback (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\binder.ts:545:22)
at C._bindDeferred (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\binder.ts:4140:22)
at C.bindModule (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\binder.ts:298:14)
at callback (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\sourceFile.ts:1197:28)
at s.timeOperation (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\common\timing.ts:40:20)
at callback (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\sourceFile.ts:1184:38)
at t.LogTracker.log (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\common\logTracker.ts:43:20)
at t.SourceFile.bind (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\sourceFile.ts:1181:33)
at O._bindFile (c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\program.ts:931:34)
at c:\Users\Farn\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2022.7.40\dist\pyright-internal\src\analyzer\program.ts:1051:18
```

Can someone help?

Thanks

Farn